# SQLAlchemy / Python / Pyramid Write To Database Issue

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, pyramid

The problem:

I am working on a bit of code that is meant to create a new record in a linking table. The linking table has a primary key that is an auto number, the other two fields are VARCHAR with a length of 10.

The issue I'm having is I cannot seem to get partID into the table. If you look at the sql output you can clearly see it write None and u'1' (the orderID) to the table. So that tells me its recieving the orderID just fine. Also you can see that I did a print to find out what is inside my variable before passing it to the new object. It has 3 in it which is the correct partId. Somewhere between creating the new object and writing to the table it passes a null.

I've tried to cast it, Ive tried different ways of pulling the partID from the database, etc and I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong.

The code:

```
def updateOrderParts_view(request):
    part = None
    partToOrder = None
    idnum = None

    part = DBSession.execute(\
    "SELECT partID "+\
    "FROM tblParts "+\
    "WHERE partName = " + "'" +request.POST['partName'] +"'").fetchone()

    print "<---DEBUG--->"
    print part['partID']

    partToOrder = PartsByOrder(part['partID'], request.POST['orderID'])

    DBSession.add(partToOrder)
    return{}
```

The terminal output:

```
<---DEBUG--->
3
2013-04-24 08:14:47,985 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine][Dummy-2] INSERT INTO "tblPartsByOrder" ("partID", "orderID") VALUES (?, ?)
2013-04-24 08:14:47,985 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine][Dummy-2] (None, u'1')
2013-04-24 08:14:47,986 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine][Dummy-2] COMMIT
```

I would appreciate any thoughts or comments on this issue

Thanks for your time

Comment: Please, please, never-ever manually construct an SQL query, especially from bits you've got from user input. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Always use bind parameters: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/expression_api.html?#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would look at doing the SQL lookup a little different, if you can. (I guess it depends, do you have a model based on "tblParts"? I'm going to use an example assuming there is a model object "Part"):

```
part = DBSession.query(Part.partID).filter(Part.partName == request.POST['partName']).first()
```

From there, I'm rusty on the exact syntax but I think you could do something like

```
print "<---DEBUG--->"
print part

partToOrder = PartsByOrder(part, request.POST['orderID'])

DBSession.add(partToOrder)

return{}
```

You might need to case "part" to a string (`str(part)`) if it's a casting problem.

Good luck,